# Websphere federated repository for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, websphere

What I am trying to achieve is to have Websphere 6.1 use Active Directory users authentication.

Websphere is running on Windows 2008 R2.

What I've done already:

1. Succesfully setup a federated repository for Windows Active Directory (LDAP);
2. Create a realm definition for the federated repository previously defined;
3. Set the realm definition as the current real definition.
4. Stop the Websphere service.

When I attempt to start the Websphere service again, it crashes with the following stacktrace:

------Start of DE processing------ = [9/3/10 2:36:14:133 PDT] , key = com.ibm.websphere.security.EntryNotFoundException com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.createCredential 824
Exception = com.ibm.websphere.security.EntryNotFoundException
Source = com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.createCredential
probeid = 824
Stack Dump = com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.EntityNotFoundException: CWWIM4001E The 'null' entity was not found.
 at com.ibm.ws.wim.registry.util.UniqueIdBridge.getUniqueUserId(UniqueIdBridge.java:233)
 at com.ibm.ws.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry$6.run(WIMUserRegistry.java:351)
 at com.ibm.ws.wim.security.authz.jacc.JACCSecurityManager.runAsSuperUser(JACCSecurityManager.java:500)
 at com.ibm.ws.wim.security.authz.ProfileSecurityManager.runAsSuperUser(ProfileSecurityManager.java:964)
 at com.ibm.ws.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry.getUniqueUserId(WIMUserRegistry.java:340)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.createCredential(UserRegistryImpl.java:750)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.authenticate(LTPAServerObject.java:776)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule.login(ltpaLoginModule.java:453)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:795)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:209)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:709)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:246)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:706)
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:603)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.JaasLoginHelper.jaas_login(JaasLoginHelper.java:376)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:3513)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:3306)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:3086)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getServerSubjectInternal(ContextManagerImpl.java:2180)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getServerSubjectInternal(ContextManagerImpl.java:1972)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.initialize(ContextManagerImpl.java:2530)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.initialize(ContextManagerImpl.java:2560)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.enable(SecurityContext.java:83)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.core.distSecurityComponentImpl.initialize(distSecurityComponentImpl.java:379)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.core.distSecurityComponentImpl.startSecurity(distSecurityComponentImpl.java:336)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityComponentImpl.startSecurity(SecurityComponentImpl.java:105)
 at com.ibm.ws.security.core.ServerSecurityComponentImpl.start(ServerSecurityComponentImpl.java:283)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:977)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:673)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:197)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:977)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:673)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:526)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:192)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:140)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:461)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:329)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:92)

Dump of callerThis = 
Object type = com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl
com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl@68a068a0

Anybody maybe has a hint on this?

I followed the exact steps described in the IBM Infocenter for setting this up.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This element of one of the first lines: 
`.UserRegistryImpl.createCredential` makes me wonder if either you have an SSL/clear text issue, or else a password issue with your account.  The usual LDAP suspects.